# does not contain a default export even after being correctly imported in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, http, django-rest-framework

I have this simple file which imports getAccesToken constant from another file. But I keep getting this error even when everything is defined perfectly. I really have no clue why would this happen. I looked similar questions on SO, but most had curly brackets when importing or something.

PS This question is a sequel to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410958/how-to-integrate-getaccesstoken-with-fetch-function-to-load-data-from-drf-backen/57411399).

This is my file importing the constant:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Card, CardBody, CardHeader, Col, Row, Table} from 'reactstrap';
import getAccessToken from '../helpers/api'   //Here is the import
import {reactLocalStorage} from "reactjs-localstorage";
import {API_TOKENS} from "../data/storage";
import {errorGettingUserInfoNotification, signINAgainNotification} from "../helpers/notifications";




class all_orders extends Component {
    state = {
        todos: []
    };


    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/allorders/',

                {
                    headers: {
                        // your headers there as pair key-value, matching what your API is expecting, for example:
                        'details': getAccessToken()
                    }
                });
            // fetching the data from api, before the page loaded
            const todos = await res.json();
            console.log(todos);
            this.setState({
                todos
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }


    render() {

        // const userList = usersData.filter((user) => user.id < 10)

        return (
            <div className="animated fadeIn">
                <Row>
                    <Col xl={12}>
                        <Card>
                            <CardHeader>
                                <i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i> All Orders <small
                                className="text-muted"></small>
                            </CardHeader>
                            <CardBody>
                                <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li className="nav-item">
                                        <a className="nav-link active"
                                           href="base/all-orders#/base/hold-orders">Active</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="nav-item">
                                        <a className="nav-item" href="base/all-orders#/base/hold-orders">Link</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="nav-item">
                                        <a className="nav-item" href="base/all-orders#/base/hold-orders">Link</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="nav-item">
                                        <a className="nav-link disabled"
                                           href="base/all-orders#/base/hold-orders">Disabled</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <Table responsive hover>
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                        <th scope="col">SKU ID</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Dimensions</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Weight</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Volume</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Origin</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Destination</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>


                                    {this.state.todos.map(item => (
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{item.name}</td>
                                            <td>{item.pid}</td>
                                            <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                                            <td>{item.length} X {item.width} X {item.height}</td>
                                            <td>{item.weight}</td>
                                            <td>{item.volume}</td>
                                            <td>{item.origin}</td>
                                            <td>{item.destination}</td>
                                            <td>{item.time}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))}


                                    </tbody>
                                </Table>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default all_orders;
```

Here is the file from where I am exporting:

```
/*
    Contains all URLs and ApiFunctions
 */
import axios from "axios";
import {reactLocalStorage} from "reactjs-localstorage";

import {API_TOKENS} from "../data/storage";
import {errorGettingUserInfoNotification, signINAgainNotification} from "./notifications";


const BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
axios.defaults.baseURL = BASE_URL;
axios.defaults.headers.get['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-urlencoded';


const GET_TOKEN_PAIR = '/sign-in/';
const CREATE_ACCOUNT = '/sign-up/';
const USERNAME_AVAILABLE = '/username/available/';
const REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN = '/refresh/';
const USER_DETAILS = "/user/meta/";


export const getAccessToken = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const data = reactLocalStorage.getObject(API_TOKENS);

        if (!data)
            return resolve('No User found');

        let access_token = '';
        const expires = new Date(data.expires * 1000);
        const currentTime = new Date();

        if (expires > currentTime) {
            access_token = data.tokens.access;
        } else {
            try {
                const new_token = await loadOpenUrl(REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN, {
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        refresh: data.tokens.refresh,
                    }
                });
                access_token = new_token.access;
                const expires = new_token.expires;

                reactLocalStorage.setObject(API_TOKENS, {
                    tokens: {
                        ...data.tokens,
                        access: access_token
                    },
                    expires: expires
                });

            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    if (e.data.code === "token_not_valid")
                        signINAgainNotification();
                    else
                        errorGettingUserInfoNotification();
                } catch (e) {
                    // pass
                }

                return reject('Error refreshing token', e);
            }
        }

        return resolve(access_token);
    });
};

export const loadOpenUrl = async (url, config = {}) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios(url, config)
            .then((res) => resolve(res.data))
            .catch(err => reject(err.response))
    });
};

export const loadSecureUrl = (url, config) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const data = await loadOpenUrl(url, {
                ...config,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${await getAccessToken()}`
                }
            });
            return resolve(data)
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e)
        }
    })
};

export const getAPITokens = async (username, password) => {
    return loadOpenUrl(GET_TOKEN_PAIR, {
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        },
        method: "post"
    })
};

export const getUserDetails = () => {

    //TODO: Show loading screen
    const data = loadSecureUrl(USER_DETAILS);

    //TODO: hide loading screen
    return data;
};


export const isUsernameAvailable = async (username) => {
    try {
        return await loadOpenUrl(USERNAME_AVAILABLE, {
            params: {
                username: username
            }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return false
    }

};

export const signUpUser = async (data) => {
    return loadOpenUrl(CREATE_ACCOUNT, {
        method: 'post',
        data: data
    })
};

export const allorders = async (data) => {
    return loadOpenUrl(CREATE_ACCOUNT, {
        method: 'post',
        data: data
    })
};
```

Error I am getting :

> Failed to compile
> ./src/screens/all_orders.js
>
> Attempted import error: '../helpers/api' does not contain a default export >(imported as 'getAccessToken').

Comment: and what is the exact error ?

Comment: `./src/screens/all_orders.js
Attempted import error: '../helpers/api' does not contain a default export (imported as 'getAccessToken').` Updated question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to import a `default module` (which was exported using `export default`), but you didn't export any default in your file.

So, because your module is not default exported you have to use brackets like this:

```
import { getAccessToken } from '../helpers/api'   //Here is the import
```

or export the module as default

```
export default const getAccessToken = () => {
```

then you can use it as you do now.

Check the doc: [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

And here is something very useful to understand quick about import/exports: [[es6] import, export, default cheatsheet](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f)

Answer (score 7):

This import is for `default export`,

```
import getAccessToken from '../helpers/api'
```

You have exported as `named export`, you should import like this,

```
import {getAccessToken} from '../helpers/api'
```

[Named Export vs Default Export in ES6](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910)

Answer (score 6):

To be more clear, there are two types of exports:

### 1- Default Exports (One per module)

in your code will be:

```
export default const getAccessToken = () => {}
```

```
import getAccessToken from '../helpers/api'
```

### 2- Named Exports (Zero or more exports per module)

in your code will be:

```
export const getAccessToken = () => {}
```

```
import {getAccessToken} from '../helpers/api'
```

- https://javascript.info/import-export
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export